A null value in a column violates the non-null constraint (PostgreSQL)
create table Portfolio_IDH
(
    ANO int,
    NOME varchar(30) unique,
    IDHM numeric(10,3) not null,
    IDHM_L numeric(10,3) not null,
    IDHM_E numeric(10,3) not null,
    IDHM_R numeric(10,3) not null,
    IDHMAD numeric(10,3) not null,
    IDHMAD_L numeric (10,3) not null,
    IDHMAD_E numeric (10,3) not null,
    IDHMAD_R numeric(10,3) not null,
    RDPC numeric(10,3),
    GINI numeric(10,3),
    THEIL numeric(10,3)
);

insert into portfolio_idh(ano) 
values (2004);

I'm a beginner in SQL and I want to know about this error about null values. I think it's because of that error that I couldn't import an Excel archive.

As you found out this is not going to work. If you do not specify a DEFAULT in the column definition the default value will be NULL. Since you are only entering a value for ano all the rest of values will get NULL as their value and those that have NOT NULL set will fail. You need to either 1) Get rid of the NOT NULL constraints. 2) Or supply non-NULL values for all fields that have NOT NULL set.

In previous comment forgot option 3) In column definition for NOT NULL fields include DEFAULT <some_not_null_value>. Then

Check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-NOT-NULL

@Adrian: It's basic stuff, your comments would still make a decent answer.

Read the error message. The words have meaning. You have 8 columns that are defined as NOT NULL, and yet your INSERT only assigns a value to one column that does not have that constraint. What do you expect will happen with those 8 NOT NULL columns when you're not setting a value for them? Rather than just pounding on your keyboard to output code you don't understand, find a good book or online tutorial on SQL and the basics of using it.

Per the docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

DEFAULT default_expr
[...]
The default expression will be used in any insert operation that does not specify a value for the column. If there is no default for a column, then the default is null.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Each column not present in the explicit or implicit column list will be filled with a default value, either its declared default value or null if there is none.

If you do not want to get the error you need to do some combination of:

Supply explicit DEFAULT non-NULL values in the column definitions that have a NOT NULL constraint.

Make sure the INSERT column list includes the NOT NULL fields and supply non-NULL values in the VALUES() section.

Change the table to not have NOT NULL constraints on the fields.


